# Private Blockchain - Mining Process - What is being mined?

Tags: go-ethereum

I created a simple private blockchain using one single step:

```
geth --dev
```

I read that it would automatically generate the genesis block.

On another console window, I created an account and started

```
miner.start()
```

When I checked my account balance

```
 eth.accounts[0].ballance

 web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]),"ether");
```

the terminal returned

```
 1020
```

I started the miner.start() again 
and when checking my balance it showed to me

```
1180
```

What is really being mined since I have no transactions, only my account creation and the genesis block?

How could I check the blocks on the blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ethereum network mining happens in a periodical interaval and block created based on the minning work and Rewarded Ether for the miner in your case accounts[0].

- Mining does not depends on number of transaction.
- Mining does not wait for a transaction to be happenned.  It is a
  periodical process
- Mining happens with or without transactions.

For checking block info:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 745600,
  highestBlock: 889152,
  startingBlock: 745553
}
```

Comment: Are these values for the blocks related to your private blockchain or are they some sort of pattern?

Comment: this is sort of pattern